Plain HTTP request dropped with wget but completes in curl
I'm logged into a console in Azure Container App contacting another Azure Container App in the same environment.
This works ...
curl -L -v http://my-other-app/filepath.js
This doesn't work ...
wget http://my-other-app/filepath.js
... and fails with wget: connection closed prematurely
The NodeJS app running in the container also fails to fetch from the sibling with ECONNRESET.
It only fails for files above about 200kb in size, other files which are smaller in size download fine e.g. favicon.ico.
What could be causing this?
